# Assigning Folder Permissions with JSOM

Tags: permissions, client-object-model

Is it possible to use JSOM to assign unique folder permissions?

I found the `SP.BasePermissions.set()` method but can't seem to find much documentation on it. Much more out there using C# but unfortunately I'm limited to using JavaScript.

EDIT: Sorry if this was unclear - In addition to breaking the role inheritance I also need to assign permissions to the folder programmatically.

Comment: A couple things would need to happen when a folder is created: `1. Break parent inheritance 2. Grant current user permissions 3. Remove all other permissions`

Comment: check this one http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/384840-assigning-unique-folder-permissions-in-sharepoint-libraries-via-powershell

Comment: Can't use powershell unfortunately

Comment: JSOM and CSOM are very similar.  Chances are, methods available in CSOM are available in JSOM; the naming conventions are just different (get_property/set_property instead of GetProperty/SetProperty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [SP.SecurableObject.breakRoleInheritance method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659518(v=office.14).aspx) to create unique role assignments for Folder.

### How to create unique role assignments for a Folder using JSOM

```
function getFolder(url,success,error) {

   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
   var folder = ctx.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url);   
   ctx.load(folder,'ListItemAllFields'); 
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function () {
         success(folder);
      }, 
      error
   );
}

function breakFolderRoleInheritance(url,success,error) 
{
    getFolder(url,function(folder){
       var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
       var folderItem = folder.get_listItemAllFields();  
       folderItem.breakRoleInheritance(false,false);

       ctx.executeQueryAsync(
         function () {
           success(folder);
         }, 
         error);
    },
    error);
}
```

**Usage**

Set unique role assignments for a folder named `Orders` located in `Documents` library:

```
breakFolderRoleInheritance('/Documents/Orders',
  function(folder){
      var folderItem = folder.get_listItemAllFields();  
      console.log(String.format('Folder {0} has unique permissions',folderItem.get_item('Title')));
  },
  function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Have you used this before in SP2010? It looks like the get_listItemAllFields() function is only available in 2013.

Comment: listItemAllFields should be in 2010 too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557727(v=office.14).aspx , did you load the property like he did: ctx.load(folder, 'ListItemAllFields')