# TreeView WebPart Property

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, treeview

Is there a way to add a list items TreeView as a WebPart Property?
Can you give me an overview on how to do this, knowing that the TreeView should contain selectable checkboxes that allow to retrieve the selected items.

I know that a custom property will be displayed automatically in the Property Pane if it’s of type **bool**, **DateTime**, **enum**, **int**, or **string**. But what if we want to add a **TreeView**, like in my case?

*(I'm under SharePoint 2013)*

Answer (score 1):

It requires custom solutions to build a tree view web part in SharePoint. Please see the references here:

[Tree View WebPart for Sharepoint List Data.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42509/Tree-View-WebPart-for-Sharepoint-List-Data)

[Sharepoint 2013 : Tree view structure for Document library and setting permissions.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154620/sharepoint-2013-tree-view-structure-for-document-library-and-setting-permissio/156075)

There are also third-party solutions that provide this function, for example:
[SharePoint Tree View - Bamboo Solutions Web Parts.](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/pfi-38-tree-view-web-part.aspx)

Comment: in fact, my problem at the beginning was not building a treeview, but rather passing the selected treeview values into the webpart's properties 

thanks to the addition of a toolpart class, I managed to create the treeview, and to pass the selected values in a string property by concatenating the values (since the webpart only considers 5 classical types: string, enum, int, ...)

I'll be sharing the solution I used soon