# SharePoint Online How to view all folders and subfolder in a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, folder, subfolders

I am using SPO, I would like to view in the document library all folders and subfolder.

For example: folder A then shows Subfolder B and Subfolder C and so on up to 4 levels (like file explorer view).

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with OOB solutions, but technically you can add a **tree-view navigation** on the page to display the folder structures.

See the references here:

Classic Experience: [Sharepoint 2013 : Tree view structure for Document library and setting permissions.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154620/sharepoint-2013-tree-view-structure-for-document-library-and-setting-permissio/156075)

Modern Experience: [Tree view navigation using PnP Treeview control in the SharePoint Framework (SPFx) web part.](https://ravichandran.blog/2020/05/14/tree-view-navigation-using-pnp-treeview-control-in-the-sharepoint-framework-spfx-web-part/)

Comment: First part is not quite correct--that aside, good answers will show rather than just link to off-site resources. When those links die (e.g. "link rot") the post loses what value it previously had.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the site in Internet Explorer then select "Open in File Explorer" from the Library ribbon tab. You'll need to make sure you have IE installed, or possibly Edge which allows you to operate in IE mode (e.g. if at work, some organizations disable or control this at an enterprise level via group-policy):

[image: Image pointing to the "Open with Explorer" option, and that option's tooltip displaying]

Clicking on it will open the traditional Windows File Explorer view in a new window:

[image: Screenshot of the Windows File Explorer view of the same content.]